# В XML удалить тег с содержимым

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Есть XML

```
<persons>
<person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк</fio><age>40</age></person>
<person><bd>12.03.1955</bd><fio>Тони Старк 2</fio><age>41</age></person>
<person><bd>12.03.1954</bd><fio>Тони Старк 3</fio><age>42</age></person>
</persons>
```

Как бы в XML пройтись циклом и удалить все теги вместе с содержимым, например тег  `<fio>`Содержимое тега`</fio>`?

Чтобы получилось так

```
<persons>
<person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><age>40</age></person>
<person><bd>12.03.1955</bd><age>41</age></person>
<person><bd>12.03.1954</bd><age>42</age></person>
</persons>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Xml.Linq;
var xml = @"<persons>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк</fio><age>40</age></person>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 2</fio><age>41</age></person>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 3</fio><age>42</age></person>
            </persons>";
var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
foreach (var x in xe.Descendants("fio").ToList())
   x.Remove();
```

Comment: @Андрей _" подправить чтение из файла и сохранение в новый файл возможно?"_ -- сохранение: xe.Save("c:\temp\out.xml"); а что надо подправить при чтении?

Comment: @Андрей _"Не код xml, а чтение из файла xml"_ -- чтение из файла, так `var xe = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\in.xml");`

Comment: Можно было и просто `xe.Descendants("fio").Remove();` - цикл там не особо нужен. А преобразование в `List<XElement>` - тем более там не нужно.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"цикл там не особо нужен"_ -- да, но обычно надо сделать что-то долнительно, а не просто убрать fio. _"преобразование в List<XElement> - тем более там не нужно"_ -- проверьте, будет System.NullReferenceException.